# Remove indent of paragraph and add line skip with tufte-latex

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, tufte, parskip

I'm using `tufte-latex` and I want paragraphs to have no indent, but a line skip instead. Normally you can achive this with:

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

Using `tufte-latex` this does not work however. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll want to redefine a couple Tufte-LaTeX commands. The current paragraph indentation and skips are set as follows:

```
\makeatletter
% Paragraph indentation and separation for normal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@reset@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1.0pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{1.0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
\@tufte@reset@par

% Paragraph indentation and separation for marginal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@margin@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
```

You can copy those commands to the preamble of your document and fill in the values that you prefer (e.g., `0pt` for the indents and `\baselineskip` for the `\parskip`).