# Remove indent of paragraph in fullwidth and add line skip with tufte-latex

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, tufte, fullwidth

The partial answer is here - [Remove indent of paragraph and add line skip with tufte-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77999/remove-indent-of-paragraph-and-add-line-skip-with-tufte-latex)

It does not work on fullwidth text. How to achieve that?

```
\documentclass[nols,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class

\begin{document}


\bigskip
\begin{fullwidth}
The design of the front matter in Tufte's books varies slightly from the traditional design of front matter. First, the pages in front matter are traditionally numbered with lowercase roman numerals ( i, ii, iii, iv,). Second, the front matter page numbering sequence is usually separate from the main matter page numbering. That is, the page numbers restart at 1 when the main matter begins. In contrast, Tufte has enumerated his pages with arabic numerals that share the same page counting sequence as the main matter.

There are also some variations in design across Tufte's four books. The page opposite the full title page (labeled ``frontispiece'' in the above table) has different content in each of the books. I

The dedication appears on page~6 in age of the introduction.

None of the page numbers (folios) ofedication page.
\end{fullwidth}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example that shows the problem? It appears to work okay for me.

Comment: Added the MWE. Please see!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short example that uses the code from the answer your linked to.  Does this achieve the effect you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides dummy text

% From <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77999>
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\makeatletter
% Paragraph indentation and separation for normal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@reset@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.0pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0.0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
}
\@tufte@reset@par

% Paragraph indentation and separation for marginal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@margin@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.0pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0.0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.0pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{10pt}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{fullwidth}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{fullwidth}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh! so it was caused by justifyingparindent... Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay. Glad you figured it out!  Since you're using the `justified` class option, you have to set the `\JustifyingParindent` parameter. Otherwise the indent will be reset by the `ragged2e` package each paragraph.

Comment: BTW, useful to know: by removing tufte in this solution the indentation for paragraphs introduced by `ragged2e` is removed for those that desire so.