# tufte-handout and footnotes

Tags: tufte

In the example below, paragraphs 1 and 2 are not indented and are separated by some vertical space, as requested by `\parindent=0pt\parskip=10pt`. However, paragraph 3 reverts to the default (some parindent, no parskip).

If I enclose `\footnote(...}` in a group as in `{\footnote(...}}`, then all is well.

Is this a bug in `tufte-handout.cls`? It works as expected in `article.cls`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\def\SOMETEXT{ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt\parskip=10pt

1.\SOMETEXT

2.\SOMETEXT\footnote{footnote text.}\SOMETEXT

3.\SOMETEXT

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paragraph formatting is reset when the `\footnote` command is used. Instead of using your `\parindent=0pt\parskip=10pt` lines, you'll need to modify a few other parameters. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78069/80) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. It's easier to enclose the `\footnote` inside a group because then the parameters are restored.

Comment: My question is *why* `\footnote` resets those parameters.

Comment: There are two sets of paragraph indentation and spacing settings: one for the main body text (`\@tufte@reset@par`) and one for margin notes, sidenotes, captions, and so forth (`\@tufte@margin@par`).  Whenever Tufte-LaTeX starts to typeset margin material, it switches to the `\@tufte@margin@par` paragraph settings.