# How to stop indentation of new paragraph in tufte-handout?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, latex3, tufte

I'm using the `tufte-handout`class, but I want to deviate slightly from the template. I would like to separate paragraphs through a small space, *not* through indentation.

I usually do this in my Latex documents by adding:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex} % show new paragraphs with a space between lines
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} % get rid of indentation for new paragraph
```

This works for the extra space between the paragraph, but it doesn't get rid of the indentation.

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex} % show new paragraphs with a space between lines
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} % get rid of indentation for new paragraph

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas libero erat, bibendum ut tellus quis, rhoncus viverra lacus. Donec vestibulum, arcu tempor aliquam posuere, odio risus consectetur lectus, nec vestibulum lorem tellus vitae est. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas neque ligula, euismod non vulputate sit amet, ultricies congue velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus eget quam massa. Donec facilisis tempus consequat. Donec tempor viverra justo. Praesent tempus rhoncus massa sit amet hendrerit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris non leo justo. Donec dapibus laoreet luctus. Sed rhoncus mi ante, quis tristique libero tempor at.

Quisque sit amet sem nec nunc pellentesque ultricies sed quis mauris. Donec vitae condimentum lacus. Fusce nec pretium tellus. Nulla molestie at nulla ut sagittis. Pellentesque imperdiet elit in neque convallis vestibulum. Aliquam lorem libero, vehicula sed semper sit amet, dapibus eget sem. Morbi eu ultrices odio.

Morbi mattis mi in mauris condimentum, non viverra orci ullamcorper. Aenean auctor erat a commodo convallis. Nunc metus nisl, ornare a ligula vel, aliquet accumsan erat. Sed id finibus magna, non porttitor odio. Nunc ut faucibus nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin lacinia venenatis mi. Morbi massa metus, mattis vel nulla quis, molestie fermentum ligula. Donec vitae lacus ac tellus imperdiet mollis. Aliquam quis augue vitae mi finibus scelerisque ac id nisi. Quisque orci eros, placerat in dui sit amet, sodales euismod elit.

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please edit and repost the image without so much white space? You could crop it with a graphic software or using `pdfcrop`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77999/remove-indent-of-paragraph-and-add-line-skip-with-tufte-latex).

Copied from above link:

```
\makeatletter
% Paragraph indentation and separation for normal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@reset@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1.0pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{1.0pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
\@tufte@reset@par

% Paragraph indentation and separation for marginal text
\renewcommand{\@tufte@margin@par}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.5pc}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
```